# I cannt use calculated columns in sql server view to get another column in the same view

Tags: sql, sql-server, function

I have a table like this
has 13 columns :
Amount, paid1, paid2, paid3, paid4, paid5, paid6, remain1, remain2, remain3, remain4, remain5, remain6
I want from sql server to make do the following

```
Remain1 = amount -  paid1
Remain2 = remain1 - paid2
Remain3 = remain2 - paid3
Remain4 = remain3 - paid4
Remain5 = remain4 - paid5
Remain6 = remain5 - paid6
```

But sql server reject that
It reject useing  caculated columns in the same view
I did the following :

```
Remain1= amount -paid1
Remain2= amount- paid1- paid2
Remain3= amount -paid1- paid2 -paid3
Remain4= amount -paid1- paid2 -paid3 -paid4
Remain5= amount -paid1- paid2 -paid3 -paid4 -paid5
Remain6= amount -paid1- paid2 -paid3 -paid4 -paid5 -paid6
```

but Its too difficult to do that with a several columns
Can any one help me

Comment: The question here, really doesn't make any sense. You reference columns called `c1`,  `c2`, etc, and then start referencing columns called `paid1`, `paid2`, etc. What happened to `c1`?

Comment: As for the problem, the error you've omitted tells you the problem. For emphasis: *"Computed column 'i2' in table 'SomeTable' **is not allowed to be used in another computed-column definition**."*

Comment: Also, it looks like you have a denormalised design here, if I am honest. Perhaps that's the root of your problem.

Comment: [Edit] your question, don't put code like that in the comments.

Comment: You can't reference a column created in the same SELECT clause. Either repeat the calculations, or do them in subqueries.

Comment: i dont  want to repeat columns

Comment: Since it's a limitation of SQL Server, i think you're stuck on repeating. If you have more than 10 "paid" columns, perhaps try to create another design which use separate table to keep track of payment details

Comment: Thank you for your interest i have many tables like this i used fuctions in these tables and many columns based on another columns so some columns take its value from a caculated column and another column based on this column i mean col a need col b and b need c and c need d  so i repeat colmn name many times and repeat functions every time

Comment: I trird to write it liike code but cannt

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Since it was rejected because you had used calculated columns in the same view.

How about you either declare #temp tables, or table variables? Then do a final select using those two tables.

Comment: Thank you sir ... I was looking a good method to got what i need coz i have many columns like that and many functions too so its not easy to make any tables again